# Ejecutar script python mediante C# .NET

Tags: c#, python, .net

Buen día.

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de `C# .NET` que necesita llamar a un `script` de `python`.

He intentado llamar el script mediante la libreria `IronPython`:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

private void processFiles()
            {
                ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                try
                {
                     engine.ExecuteFile(@"Script.py");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteLine("Error al procesar los archivos: ");
                    WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    procesado = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Pero me da el siguiente mensaje de error:

> No module named os.path

Significa que no puedo importar librerias dentro del script. La duda es **¿Existe alguna manera de crear un compilado python y ejecutar el mismo desde .NET?** o **¿Hay alguna manera de ejecutar el script con todas sus dependencias?**

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Si solo necesitas ejecutar un Script de python  y no interactuar con él, tal vez lo mejor sea simplemente ejecutarlo como cualquier comando `Process.Start("<path a python.exe>","Script.py");`.